# Java iText PdfPTable larger than 6 columns

Tags: java, pdf, itext, calculated-columns, tabular

I want to modify a table that is generated by iText to have one more column.

But when I change the constructor argument from:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
```

to:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);
```

and add content to it like I do to other columns:

```
cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(name));
    cell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(cell1);
```

The table doesn't exist in the generated PDF. Why is that? I'm guessing it does not fit the document width?

Comment: Are you adding a sufficient number of cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that this works (it does work, I know):

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
table.addCell("1");
table.addCell("2");
table.addCell("3");
table.addCell("4");
table.addCell("5");
table.addCell("6");
document.add(table);
```

In this case, a table with a single row and 6 columns will be added.

If you change this snippet like this, no table will be added:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);
table.addCell("1");
table.addCell("2");
table.addCell("3");
table.addCell("4");
table.addCell("5");
table.addCell("6");
document.add(table);
```

This table won't be added, because there is only a single row in it, and incomplete rows aren't rendered.

You have two options, either you add:

```
table.completeRow();
```

Or you add:

```
table.addCell("7");
```

right before adding the `table` to the `document`.

There is no reason why you could add a table with 6 columns but not a table with 7 columns. Width isn't an issue: if you don't define an absolute width for the columns, then iText will calculate the exact width of each column automatically.

I don't know if I have a document with a table that has 7 columns, but I do have an example of a table that has 8: see the [SimpleTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable) example and [simple_table.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/simple_table.pdf).